# Rearrange index of dataframe to move string to top

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as such:

```
    LC_REF     a       vals
0 DT 16 2C     a      Jon,Foo,Bar
1 DT 16 2C     a      Foo,bar,foobar,random,info
2 DT 16 2C     a      random, teddy, roosevelt
3 DT 16 3C     a      filler, info
4 DT 16 3C     a      apple
5 DT 16 3C     a      foobar,foo,bar
6 DT 16 3C     a      foobar
7 DT 17 1C     a      random,info,to,be,moved
8 DT 17 1C     a      apple
9 DT 17 1C     a      foo, aabr
10 DT 17 1C    a      aabr,foo
11 DT 17 2C    a      touchy
12 DT 17 2C    a      wtf
13 DT 17 2C    a      foo,bar
14 DT 17 3C    a      do
15 DT 17 3C    a      tetris
```

I would like to groupby LC_REF and move 'Apple' to the top of each groupby, while preserving the same order. So final output would hopefully look like this:

```
    LC_REF     a       vals
0 DT 16 2C     a      Jon,Foo,Bar
1 DT 16 2C     a      Foo,bar,foobar,random,info
2 DT 16 2C     a      random, teddy, roosevelt
4 DT 16 3C     a      apple
3 DT 16 3C     a      filler, info
5 DT 16 3C     a      foobar,foo,bar
6 DT 16 3C     a      foobar
8 DT 17 1C     a      apple
7 DT 17 1C     a      random,info,to,be,moved
9 DT 17 1C     a      foo, aabr
10 DT 17 1C    a      aabr,foo
11 DT 17 2C    a      touchy
12 DT 17 2C    a      wtf
13 DT 17 2C    a      foo,bar
14 DT 17 3C    a      do
15 DT 17 3C    a      tetris
```

I've tried some kind of variation with groupby and reindex to no avail:

```
df.groupby('LC_REF').reindex(['apple'])
```

but I honestly don't know how to word this syntax, or if i am even on the right track. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is with dual `.loc` increment and decrement of index values i.e

```
df = df.reset_index()

df.loc[df.loc[df['vals'].str.contains('apple'),'index']-1,'index']+=1
df.loc[df['vals'].str.contains('apple'),'index']-=1
df = df.set_index('index',drop=True).sort_index()
```

Output :

```
         LC_REF  a                        vals
index                                         
0      DT 16 2C  a                 Jon,Foo,Bar
1      DT 16 2C  a  Foo,bar,foobar,random,info
2      DT 16 2C  a    random, teddy, roosevelt
3      DT 16 3C  a                       apple
4      DT 16 3C  a                filler, info
5      DT 16 3C  a              foobar,foo,bar
6      DT 16 3C  a                      foobar
7      DT 17 1C  a                       apple
8      DT 17 1C  a     random,info,to,be,moved
9      DT 17 1C  a                   foo, aabr
10     DT 17 1C  a                    aabr,foo
11     DT 17 2C  a                      touchy
12     DT 17 2C  a                         wtf
13     DT 17 2C  a                     foo,bar
14     DT 17 3C  a                          do
15     DT 17 3C  a                      tetris
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Beautiful, it worked, thanks! I still have much to learn about pandas and Python it seems